# Database Table and Object relationship

Tags: database, object-oriented

I am a Computer Science student and one of my first class was Object Oriented Design (Java). Unfortunately, we never interacted with a database during that class. I am currently working on a CRUD app as a side-project and I am confused about the relationship between **Objects** and **DB Tables**.

Let's say I am making a persistent browser war game in Python (such as Travian), where each user has 1 or more `village`, each `village` has different buildings and troops.

Using MySQL, I could represent a `village` like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `village` (
  `village_id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int NOT NULL,
  `city_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `location-x` int(3),
  `location-y` int(3),
  `population` int(5),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`),
  PRIMARY KEY (`village_id`)
)
```

I could also make a class to represent a village using Python. But if my **Class** components are the same as my **Table** columns, isn't a waste of resources? Like rather than updating the object, why not directly interact with the database table and directly `read, write, update` values directly on the table rather than the object?